# Error in populating line chart on google graph using their api

Tags: javascript, google-api

Below is my code to chart the graph through google graph api:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var newData =[];
         for(var j = 0; j<dates.length;j++){
                newData.push([dates[j],close[j]]);
                document.write(newData[j] + "<br>");
              }
 var numRows = newData.length;
              var numCols = newData[0].length;
              data.addColumn('number', "X");
              data.addColumn('number', "Y");

for (var j = 0; j < numRows; j++){
              data.addRow(newData[j]);
          }
```

The line `document.write(newData[j] + "<br>");` in the code above prints out values below:

```
20151229,108.74
20151228,106.82
20151224,108.03
20151223,108.61
20151222,107.23
```

From that I guess that, my values are in newData are properly stored but when I tried adding to `data.addRow` it just couldn't work. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the first set of data as a date not a number. You would need to change the `data.addColumn('number', "X");` to `data.addColumn('date', "X");` and do a little conversion to make the first number a date: `new Date(newdata[j][0].toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3"))` (I used a regex, but there are other ways to convert that number to a proper javascript date)

Here is a fiddle with the example fleshed out: https://jsfiddle.net/cpadwzhL/